# Vencimento de parcela por período

Tags: php

O trecho do código abaixo exibe uma simulação de parcelamento, com data de vencimento fixa, dividido de 30 em 30 dias!

Eu gostaria de incluir um vencimento `periodico`, por exemplo de 20 em 20 dias, ou 10 em 10, de acordo com a variável `$periodicidade`.

Meu código:

```
<?php
function calcula_parcelas($num_parcelas, $vencimento_primeira_parcela = null){
  if($vencimento_primeira_parcela != null)
  {
    $vencimento_primeira_parcela = explode('/',$vencimento_primeira_parcela);
    $dia = $vencimento_primeira_parcela[0];
    $mes = $vencimento_primeira_parcela[1];
    $ano = $vencimento_primeira_parcela[2];
  }
  else
  {
    $dia = date('d');
    $mes = date('m');
    $ano = date('Y');
  }
  
  $periodicidade = 20;
 
  for($parcela = 0; $parcela < $num_parcelas; $parcela++)
  {
      if ($periodicidade == 30)
          echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$parcela. " month", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano))),'<br/>';
      else
          echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$parcela. " month", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $periodicidade, $ano))),'<br/>';
  }
}
 
//echo 'Calcula as parcela a partir de hoje<br/>';
//calcula_parcelas(5);
//echo '<br/><br/>';
echo 'Calcula as parcela a partir de uma data informada<br/>';
calcula_parcelas(5, '10/10/2020');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer estipular um variação diária fixa entre o intervalo de emissão de suas parcelas esse intervalo deve ser inicialmente computado em dias.
Informe a função `calcula_parcelas()` o intervalo em dias entre as parcelas e o multiplique pelo o número da parcela, lembrando que a primeira parcela é a parcela `0`.

- Do código original eu adicionei um novo parâmetro `$intervalo` cujo o valor na falta é 30 dias.
- Removi a variável `$periodicidade`.
- Alterei o calculo para data de emissão das parcelas passei de mensal para diário
- Removi a marcação *HTML* para facilitar a visualização no console de testes.

Veja o exemplo:

```
//Adicionei um novo parâmetro $intervalo representando o número de dias entre cada parcela.
function calcula_parcelas($num_parcelas, $vencimento_primeira_parcela = null, $intervalo=30){
  if($vencimento_primeira_parcela != null)
  {
    $vencimento_primeira_parcela = explode('/',$vencimento_primeira_parcela);
    $dia = $vencimento_primeira_parcela[0];
    $mes = $vencimento_primeira_parcela[1];
    $ano = $vencimento_primeira_parcela[2];
  }
  else
  {
    $dia = date('d');
    $mes = date('m');
    $ano = date('Y');
  }
  
  

  for($parcela = 0; $parcela < $num_parcelas; $parcela++)
  {
     //Ao invés de incrementar a data da parcela mensalmente agora ela é incrementada em um 
     //intervalo de dias informado pelo parâmetro $intervalo
     echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.($parcela * $intervalo). " day", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano))),PHP_EOL;          
  }
}
 
echo 'Calcula 5 parcelas quinzenais a partir de 10/10/2020.'.PHP_EOL;
calcula_parcelas(5, '10/10/2020',15);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Calcula 24 parcelas a decenais partir de 10/10/2020.'.PHP_EOL;
calcula_parcelas(24, '10/10/2020',10);
```

Resultado:

```
Calcula 5 parcelas quinzenais a partir de 10/10/2020.
10/10/2020
25/10/2020
09/11/2020
24/11/2020
09/12/2020

Calcula 24 parcelas a decenais partir de 10/10/2020.
10/10/2020
20/10/2020
30/10/2020
09/11/2020
19/11/2020
29/11/2020
09/12/2020
19/12/2020
29/12/2020
08/01/2021
18/01/2021
28/01/2021
07/02/2021
17/02/2021
27/02/2021
09/03/2021
19/03/2021
29/03/2021
08/04/2021
18/04/2021
28/04/2021
08/05/2021
18/05/2021
28/05/2021
```

Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DapperPassionateAddons)

Comment: Sensacional, muito obrigado por isso!